# Css and js Not Loadind in spring mvc application

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, authentication

I am trying to create an application in Spring MVC. I want to create login page using style-sheets and js files in jsp file. But I'm unable to load css and js files at the login file.

1)
I tried using:

```
<link  href=" <c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> " rel="stylesheet">
```

By using (in springWeb.xml):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

2) I directly used

```
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I loaded the page, resources (CSS/Js files) have not been loaded.

What is missing / what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not "web guy", but this question seems messy to me. Please add some more code / structure of files. thanks

Comment: Hi I updated the question Please check once and Reply .

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [ResourceHandlerRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html)?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Arpit suggested in his answer, you probably want to declare a resource handler in your configuration class.

What did the trick for me was to put a link in like this, especially the "media" attribute seemed to make the difference for my application.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

On top of that you need to pay extra attention to the path you declare in the resource handler and the actual path.